# Query from array structure

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, ddl

I have a db table called ex_table and 
Location is a column.

when i ran query it shows array structure. 
I need extract array element.

My Query was

`Select location form ex_table`
it shows

`[{country=BD, state=NIL, city=NIL}]`

how do I select only city form location column?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: its from aws athena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT location
  FROM ex_table
)
SELECT places.city
FROM dataset, UNNEST (location) AS t(places)
```

As this is an array of objects, you need to flatten the data. This is done using the `UNNEST` syntax in Athena. More info on this can be found in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html#filtering-with-unnest)

Comment: your query, show error
 ```INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: SQL array indices start at 1```

if i Query
```SELECT
  element_at(location,1) AS city
FROM dataset```

that time it output 

```{country=BD, state=NIL, city=NIL}```

Comment: @ZahidUanNabi Apologies, your question was a bit more complex than I first anticipated. You need to flatten this structure to get the desired result. Try my revised query.